# Extracting Capture Group Using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am simply trying to capture a string surrounded static text. I'll illustrate by example.  Here is the string I'm working with ...

```
String idInfo = "Any text up here\n" +
                "Here is the id\n" +
                "\n" +
                "?a0 12 b5\n" +
                "&Edit Properties...\n" +
                "And any text down here";
```

Or in pretty print ...

```
Any text up here
Here is the id

?a0 12 b5
&Edit Properties...
And any text down here
```

And I'm using the following code to try and print the ID number ...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Here is the id\n\n\?[a-z0-9]{2}( [a-z0-9]{2}){2}\n&Edit Properties...);
Matcher m = p.matcher(idInfo);
String idNum = m.group(1);
System.out.println(idNum);
```

And I want to simply output the ID number, so the output I desire for this example is ...

```
a0 12 b5
```

However, I'm getting a "No match found" exception when I run my code.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a simpler, more elegant way to accomplish my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let Matcher `find` match before you use it. So invoke `m.find()` (or `m.matches()` depending on your goal) before accessing `m.group(1);`. Also check if match was actually found (if `m.find()` retuned `true`) to make sure that group 1 exists.

Other thing is that string representing your regex is incorrect. If you want to escape `?` in regex you need to write `\` as two `"\\"` because `\` is special character in String (used for instance to create `\n`) which also needs escaping.

Last thing you pointed yourself in comment is that `( [a-z0-9]{2})` wouldn't put match `a0 12 b5` in group 1. To solve this problem we need to surround `[a-z0-9]{2}( [a-z0-9]{2}){2}` in parenthesis.

So try maybe

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Here is the id\n\n\\?([a-z0-9]{2}( [a-z0-9]{2}){2})\n&Edit Properties...");
Matcher m = p.matcher(idInfo);

if (m.find()) {//or while(m.find())
    String idNum = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(idNum);
}
```

Comment: Your code is lacking the parentheses for the capture group around the ID too.  Discovered that in testing.  I believe it should be "Here is the id\n\n\\?([a-z0-9]{2}( [a-z0-9]{2}){2})\n&Edit Properties..."    correct?

Comment: @user2150250 Yes, you are correct. I missed that my code wasn't returning output you described in your question. Fixed now.